# Async Batch jobs stuck?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

We have been using Async Batch Jobs for a while now, to process PDF files without converting them to images first. This worked fine, up till last night. After creating the job, the job never seems to get finished. We had a job stuck for 11 hours, after canceling the job I tried some other PDF jobs and they all get stuck.

We upload the files to GCP Storage, start an AsyncBatchAnnotateFilesRequest with Feature_DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION, we then use operation.Wait() so that it check the jobs status every 45 seconds to check whether it's done yet. We do this using the Go library.

Any one else seeing this issues or know what could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen to me starting last night, guessing something changed on Google's side. What worked for me was making sure the directory/files it was outputting to didn't exist first.

```
Iterable<Blob> blobs = storage.list(outputBucketName,
    BlobListOption.prefix(outputFolderName.replaceAll("^[^/]*/", ""))).iterateAll();
for (Blob blob : blobs) {
    blob.delete(Blob.BlobSourceOption.generationMatch());
}
```

EDIT: Actually maybe it was just completely unrelated, google didn't provide details but said it should no longer be stuck now:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-vision-discuss/p0PbNQ2KMGg

Comment: Yeah, that's me on Google groups. Something was wrong at Google's end. Can't believe they only noticed after the topic. Almost 1 day of downtime.